# #Query to populate different results on specific criteria. (challenger query)

Tags: mysql

Please any one assist us to resolve our ultimate challenger query.

Table Name : `attendance_tbl`

```
nota_id represents present or absent nota_id ='1' => PRESENT

priod_id

1=>Hour-1 

2=>Hour-2

3=>Hour-3

4=>Hour-4

5=>Hour-5
```

if priod_id contains value 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 then on basis of condition we have set percentage as 0.25

if priod_id contains 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 then on basis of condition we have set percentage 0.2.

if priod_id has more than 4,if it has value 5 on any day then we have set percentage to 0.2 for all 1,2,3,and4

if priod_id is with in 4 we have to set percentage to 0.25 for all 1,2,3,4

Example :

```
Date : 2018-08-31
priod_id =1 , priod_id =2 priod_id =5
Then set Percentage = 0.2 for 1,2,5

priod_id =1 , priod_id =2 priod_id =4
Then set Percentage = 0.25 for 1,2,4 

Please refer to the query we have tried the least.


SELECT *, 
      IF(`nota_id` = '1', Percentage,'0.0') AS ABSENT 
from (SELECT *, CASE WHEN (max(`priod_id`) > 4) THEN "0.2" 
                     ELSE "0.25" 
                END as Percentage 
      FROM `attendance_tbl` 
      WHERE DATE(attend_date) BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-31' 
        AND sid = '74' 
      GROUP BY sid, attend_date) t
```

[Table Results & Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elcSh.jpg)

Comment: Please rephrase your question by showing sample input data and the expected output, both formatted as _text_, directly in your question.  Add four or more spaces to each line of data to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

We found answer.

SELECT *,
           CASE 
             WHEN(max(`priod_id`) > 4) THEN 
               "0.2" 
             ELSE 
               "0.25" 
           END AS PERCENTAGE,
           COUNT(priod_id) as HOURS,
           COUNT(CASE 
                   WHEN nota_id = '1' THEN 
                     1 
                 END) AS PR
      FROM `attendance_tbl` A 
     WHERE DATE(attend_date) BETWEEN DATE('2018-08-01') AND DATE('2018-08-31') 
       AND sid = '60' 
  GROUP BY DATE(attend_date)